# How can I create online support like this link (in Persian sayed سایت همسریابی)?

Tags: asp.net

How can I create online support like that of [this site](http://www.hamsaronline.com/contactus/default.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click on the link at the bottom of [this form](http://messenger.yahoo.com/pingbox/), register, and get your own Yahoo Pingbox.